# Calling method inside __str__ function in python class

Tags: python, function, class, methods

`'List' object has no attribute 'points'` is the error I'm getting. I think I'm not calling `points` correctly inside the `__str__` function, but don't know how to fix it. Before, I had `points` defined before `__str__` and had the same error.

```
class Persons(object):

    def __init__(self,name,radius,home_universe,x,y,dx,dy,current_universe,rewards):

        self.name = name
        self.radius = radius
        self.home_universe = home_universe
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dx = dx
        self.dy = dy
        self.current_universe = current_universe
        self.rewards = rewards

    def __str__(self):

        return '{} of {} in universe {}\n at ({},{}) speed ({},{}) with {} rewards and {} points'.\
               format(self.name, self.home_universe, self.current_universe, self.x, self.y, self.dx,\
                      self.dy, len(self.rewards), self.rewards.points())

    def points(self):

        cnt = 0
        if len(self.rewards) == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            for reward in self.rewards:
                cnt += reward[2] 
            return cnt
```

Comment: what is `self.rewards` ? why do you use `self.rewards.points()` if you have only `self.points()` ?

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: You are calling `self.rewards.points()`. The error message indicates that `self.rewards` is a `List` which has no `points` attribute. Perhaps you meant `self.points()` as @furas suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `self.rewards.points()` but you have only `self.points()`.

Use `self.points()`